# Trim end of string

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I'm having trouble trimming off some characters at the end of a string. The string usually looks like:

```
C:\blah1\blah2
```

But sometimes it looks like:

```
C:\blah1\blah2.extra
```

I need to extract out the string 'blah2'. Most of the time, that's easy with a substring command. But on the rare occasions when the '.extra' portion is present, I need to first trim that part off.

The thing is, '.extra' always begins with a dot, but then is followed by various combinations of letters with various lengths. So wildcards will be necessary. Essentially, I need to script, "If the string contains a dot, trim off the dot and anything following it."

`$string.replace(".*","")` doesn't work. Nor does `$string.replace(".\*","")`. Nor does `$string.replace(".[A-Z]","")`.

Also, I can't get at it from the beginning of the string either. 'blah1' is unknown and of various lengths. I have to get at 'blah2' from the end of the string.

Comment: Are the strings always a path to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the string is always a path to a file with or without an extension (such as ".extra"), you can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\blah1\blah2")
blah2
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\blah1\blah2.extra")
blah2
```

The path doesn't even have to be rooted:

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("blah1\blah2.extra")
blah2
```

---

If you want to implement similar functionality on your own, that should be fairly simply as well - use `String.LastIndexOf()` to find the *last* `\` in the string and use that as your starting argument for `Substring()`:

```
function Extract-Name {
    param($NameString)

    # Extract part after the last occurrence of \
    if($NameString -like '*\*') {
        $NameString = $NameString.Substring($NameString.LastIndexOf('\') + 1)
    }

    # Remove anything after a potential .
    if($NameString -like '*.*') {
        $NameString.Remove($NameString.IndexOf("."))
    }

    $NameString
}
```

And you'll see similar results:

```
PS C:\> Extract-Name "C:\blah1\blah2.extra"
blah2
PS C:\> Extract-Name "C:\blah124323\blah2.extra"
blah2
PS C:\> Extract-Name "C:\blah124323\blah2"
blah2
PS C:\> Extract-Name "abc124323\blah2"
blah2
```

Comment: And if the file path is retrieved from a `FileInfo`-Object from `Get-ChildItem`, then he could use the `BaseName` property like `Get-ChildItem | % { $_.BaseName }`

Comment: Works great, Mathias. Thank you. I should have mentioned, the string is a folder path, not a file path.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters have said, you can use special file name manipulators for this. If you'd like to do it with regular expressions, you can say

`$string.replace("\..*","")`

The `\..*` regex matches a dot (`\.`) and then any string of characters (`.*`).

Let me address each of the non-working regexes individually:

> `$string.replace(".*","")`

The reason this doesn't work is that `.` and `*` are both special characters in regular expressions: `.` is a wildcard character that matches any character, and `*` means "match the previous character zero or more times." So `.*` means "any string of characters."

> `$string.replace(".\*","")`

In this instance, you're escaping the `*` character, meaning that the regex treats it literally, so the regex matches any single character (`.`) followed by a star (`\*`).

> `$string.replace(".[A-Z]","")`

In this case, the regex will match any character (`.`) followed by any single capital letter (`[A-Z]`).

Comment: Thanks for the regex explanations.

Comment: `String.Replace()` does **not** support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are actual paths using `Get-Item` would be another option:

```
$path = 'C:\blah1\blah2.something'
(Get-Item $path).BaseName
```

The [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method can't be used here, because it doesn't support wildcards or regular expressions.